# How to make button for twitter browser sign in

Tags: javascript, twitter

Hi all I'm going nuts I've been trying for 2 days.

I want my application im making to use the twitter browser sign in. I need to make a simple button that when clicked pops up "authorize" or "login" if they arent logged in.

I tried following this here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter

I get stuck at first step, it tells me to make a POST request??? What on earth, I need a button that links to twitter authorize my app I could understand putting my app api key in the form but I can't make a post with html..

Please help

Whats confusing the heck out of me, it says "Keep the API Secret a secret as in dont share it" but then it looks like I have to put it in the code? So confusing.

Then this here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter

Says to post for token which takes me here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token

And here it says the only required parameter is oauth_callback.

Then all over it says do not use oauth in javascript, so how on earth do we do it in javascript, my hand hurts not just my head. Please please help

Comment: The only info on my app page is this "AjONvgAdbD8YWCtRn5U9yA" the other is API secret nad it says not to share that or put that into your code.

Comment: you can also use a lib like this one https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-js

Comment: and there are so many examples here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/open-source-examples

Comment: it says ```cb.setConsumerKey("YOURKEY", "YOURSECRET");``` i thought the ```YOURSECRET``` should be not in the cide?  as in i should keep secret to myself?